# Duplicate class found issue in Android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, duplicates

This is a common issue and it's been asked many times with different dependencies and I've tried with the solutions provided, but non of them worked and still getting the same error.

It is a react native project, when compiling for Android, it keeps getting the following errors:

```
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapCroppingWorkerJob found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapCroppingWorkerJob$Result found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapCroppingWorkerJob$onPostExecute$2 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapCroppingWorkerJob$start$1 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapCroppingWorkerJob$start$1$1 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerJob found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerJob$Result found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerJob$onPostExecute$2 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerJob$start$1 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapUtils found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapUtils$BitmapSampled found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapUtils$RotateBitmapResult found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.BitmapUtils$WhenMappings found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropException found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropException$Cancellation found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropException$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropException$FailedToDecodeImage found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropException$FailedToLoadBitmap found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropFileProvider found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImage found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImage$ActivityResult found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImage$ActivityResult$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImage$ActivityResult$Companion$CREATOR$1 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImage$CancelledResult found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$Source found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$WhenMappings found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$onCreate$1 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$showIntentChooser$ciIntentChooser$1 found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageAnimation found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageContract found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageContractOptions found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageIntentChooser found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageIntentChooser$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageIntentChooser$ResultCallback found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageOptions found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageOptionsKt found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$CropCornerShape found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$CropResult found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$CropShape found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$Guidelines found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$OnCropImageCompleteListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$OnSetCropOverlayMovedListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$OnSetCropOverlayReleasedListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$OnSetCropWindowChangeListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$OnSetImageUriCompleteListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$RequestSizeOptions found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView$ScaleType found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropOverlayView found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropOverlayView$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropOverlayView$CropWindowChangeListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropOverlayView$ScaleListener found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropOverlayView$WhenMappings found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropWindowHandler found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropWindowHandler$WhenMappings found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropWindowMoveHandler found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropWindowMoveHandler$Companion found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropWindowMoveHandler$Type found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.CropWindowMoveHandler$WhenMappings found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.databinding.CropImageActivityBinding found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.databinding.CropImageViewBinding found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.utils.GetFilePathFromUriKt found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
Duplicate class com.canhub.cropper.utils.GetUriForFileKt found in modules jetified-Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.1-runtime (com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1) and jetified-android-image-cropper-4.5.0-runtime (com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0)
```

I've tried adding the following but non of them worked.

Force to use com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0, not working.

```
configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Exclude com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper, not working

```
implementation('com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.github.CanHub', module: 'Android-Image-Cropper'
}
```

Constraint to com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0, not working.

```
constraints {
    implementation("com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0") {
        because("android-image-cropper is already in com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding configurations all to exclude the lib like the following in build.gradle (:app) resolved the issue.

```
android {
    ...
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: 'com.github.CanHub', module: 'Android-Image-Cropper'
        }
    }
}
```